# add class along with cookeis

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I am creating  a wish list ,using cookies

But after adding the item to the list , an additional class name to be added to the item  .

But i added the class using jquery fn addClass .But it is getting cleared on each refresh

Can any body help me for this one 
Here is the jq script for adding the item to the wishlist cart

```
$(".addToWish").click(function(){
    $clicked_elem = $(this);                
    $prdct_id = $(this).closest(".wishItem").attr("data-id");
    ajaxurl1 = '<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';                                        
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl1, { prdct_id : $prdct_id, action : 'add'}).done(function(data) {                    
        if(data == "found") {
            alert("Item already added to wishlist.");                       
        } else if(data == "added") {                        
            add_item_thumb($prdct_id);
            $('.wishCounter').load('shortlist-total.php').fadeIn();
            $(".addToWish i").addClass("fa-heart"); //added class , but gets cleared
        } else {            
            alert("Server communication error");                    
        }
    });             
});
```

Comment: It will get cleared after refresh as it isn't in the original code, you might want to save it in Local Storage as it will be easier and can be done without any server side.

Comment: I dont think that will work.Because it should add and remove the particular class when ever i add and remove the item from / to the wish list cart . So it would work with the cookie :(

Comment: Track cart state either in localStorage or server session

Comment: can you give me an example